# Barcode Scanner trouble splitting into Array for individual textbox display

Tags: c#, winforms, barcode-scanner, hid

I am trying to take an input from a USB barcode scanner, that gives my an output in the following format:
"04CEA-06-250UW-350              5   A106AD548    350.0 0.3      2.1300.5     0.5     0.5        +0.5 0.2     0.2     0.2+1.5 201933US05230545    -2.15+2 +5.49+0 -4.36-2 +1.29-4 -1.80-7 +1.24-10-7.98+1 +5.52+0 -1.04-1 +6.27-4 -1.68-6 +2.34-9 1018 Steel                                                         MMF003247         y US"

this goes straight into a text box and an event handler for the textchanged then passes this through a split to parse into individual array segments and remove all the whitespace. to test this i print it to a second textbox with each component on an individual line, however the array only ever gets 1 index filled with the first group of the string "04CEA-06-250UW-350" and my form application excepts out with "index was outside the bounds of the array" if i try to print anything other than lines[0] to another textbox, i believe this may be due to the time taken for the scanner to write the string to the tb, but getting increasingly frustrated with it. the scanner is an RS pro one and i can't find any configuration details, have tried using keydown and keyEnter events to trigger the split to no avail.

```
 private void tbScanResults_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            string str = this.tbScanResults.Text;

            //remove the white space
            string pattern = "\\s+";
            string replace = " ";
            Regex rx = new Regex(pattern);

            string nowhitespace = rx.Replace(str, replace);

            //just to clean up
            nowhitespace = nowhitespace.TrimStart();
            nowhitespace = nowhitespace.TrimEnd();

            //now split the string
            string[] lines = nowhitespace.Split( ' ' );

            //output the result
            int count = 0;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var item in lines)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Item {0}: {1}", count++, item.ToString()));
                
            }

            //write the value to the output
            this.textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();

            //char[] dilimArray = new char[] { ' ', ':', '\r', '\n' };
            //string[] str2 = textBox1.Text.Split(dilimArray);

            
            tbGageFactor.Text = lines[5];
```

Comment: If you have configured the scanner as a keyboard then each character goes in separately. You need a small delay to wait for all the characters, so you start or reset a timer on each `TextChanged`. Also `tbGageFactor.Text = lines[5];` how do you know it has 6 values? You need to check `lines.Length`

Comment: i think i may have managed to solve this by using a standard timer, starting it when the event fires and then doing the writing of the separate values in the timer tick event

Comment: Usually, barcode scanners add a carriage return at the end of the code (plus a line feed, eventually), so you know when the code has ended and this also allows to move the focus, if needed. Also common, scanners can be configured to send a prefix and/or a suffix code, to delimit multiple scans or otherwise determine the extent of the code. -- You don't need a Regex at all there.

Answer (score 0):

by adding a timer, it seems i have been able to do what was needed, see code:

```
private void tbScanResults_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.timer1.Start();

            string str = this.tbScanResults.Text;

            //remove the white space
            string pattern = "\\s+";
            string replace = " ";
            Regex rx = new Regex(pattern);

            string nowhitespace = rx.Replace(str, replace);

            //just to clean up
            nowhitespace = nowhitespace.TrimStart();
            nowhitespace = nowhitespace.TrimEnd();

            //now split the string
            lines = nowhitespace.Split(' ');

            //output the result
            int count = 0;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var item in lines)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Item {0}: {1}", count++, item.ToString()));

            }

            //write the value to the output
            this.textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();

            //char[] dilimArray = new char[] { ' ', ':', '\r', '\n' };
            //string[] str2 = textBox1.Text.Split(dilimArray);


            

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbGageType.Text = lines[0];
            tbGageResistance.Text = lines[3];
            tbGageFactor.Text = lines[5].Remove(5);
        }
    }
```

Screen shot of the form:
[image]

Comment: You should still check in `timer1_Tick` that the array actually has the correct `Length`, also you probably want to disable the timer after the first run, until the next time a barcode is scanned